# Create ASM instance in 11.2g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

Now i am try to create new instance on my machine using cmd follow command like

ORADIM -new –ASMSID +ASM –STARTMODE manual -ASMSRVC asmsrvc1 -PFILE E:\app\ShreeGanesh\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\database\SPFILEORCL.ORA

cmd shows me error like 
DIM-00003: An argument is missing for the parameter.

give me better solution , so i can create new instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding -syspwd argument to your command, like so - 
ORADIM -new –ASMSID +ASM –STARTMODE manual -ASMSRVC asmsrvc1 -PFILE E:\app\ShreeGanesh\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\database\SPFILEORCL.ORA -syspwd change_on_install

You should also consider using the DBCA for such operations.

Best of luck.

Comment: So I have to recommend using DBCA to create your instance. You can also use to generate an ORADIM command and see what was wrong in your command.